# Freezing path at the moment of creating EXE file with PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-3.8

I'm creating a EXE file from a python script using PyInstaller.

On my script I'm creating a GUI using tkinter and on the GUI I have added a favicon and a image.
Because the code can be use by any member of my team in any computer, the path to the image and favicon should be as general as it can be.
For this reason I'm using from the os library the following

```
os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

and also

```
os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
```

so my code looks as follows:

```
import os
images_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

favicon_name = 'favicon.ico'
root.iconbitmap(f'{images_path}/img/{favicon_name}')

logo_name = 'logo.png'
image = Image.open(f'{images_path}/img/{logo_name}')
image = image.resize((450, 120), Image.ANTIALIAS)
logo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
logo_image_label = tk.Label(image=logo_image)
logo_image_label.pack()
```

This works when calling the script directly from the command line but when creating a EXE file with PyInstaller it will search for the favicon and image on the folder where the EXE file is run.
This means that the image and favicon should be located on a img folder in the same location the EXE file is located.

I also try using pathlib with no success

```
import pathlib
pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
```

and

```
import pathlib
pathlib.Path().absolute()
```

Because I wish to be able to send the EXE file alone to anybody who will use it with out the need of also sending the image and favicon, I wish to "freeze" this path at the time of the EXE creation so the image and favicon will not need to bee in the same folder as the EXE file or in the same computer as the EXE file.

If I use a hard-code path, for example "C:/documents/pictures/logo.png" then it will work and the picture will be show when running the EXE file even if the picture is not located in the computer or device where then EXE is running. But as mention before, hard-coding the path is not a solution because the script and PyInstaller should be able to run in any computer.

Sending the image and favicon together with the EXE file is not an option because this opens issues as the user being able to change the icon and image and we will not like that.

Comment: Seems like you want to bundle the files into the onefile exe? On the PyInstaller command line You can specify `—add-data  path/to/icon;.` and the icon file will be put in “.” which is the root folder where the exe is extracted at runtime, then in your code decide if you are running from source or exe (if exe then use sys._MEIPASS to locate your icon) - the documentation tells you how to do this. See https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#. See here for bundling options https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search

Comment: @barny. Thanks for commenting.
I'm already bundling into one file with the -F flag and tried using the --add-data flag but yet have to try the sys._MEIPASS.
I'll read the information you recommended and will implement it in my code.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I use the information under "Using __file__" on the Pyinstaller runtime documentation https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#